# How to take binding information from outside App.config in C# console application?

Tags: c#-4.0, app-config

I have an App.config fiel in which i defined some binding information.
I want this information in some external file so that user can change it whenever required.
Anyone have an idea about how to implement it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking about assembly binding redirects...

The runtime is going to use your App.exe.config file to locate the binding redirects. I don't believe you can do anything about this in a normal managed application because the runtime is already initialized by the time you can run any code.

If you had an unmanaged "shim" (an exe in C++ for example) that used the CLR hosting API's, you can tell it the name of a config file to use when you set up the AppDomain. But I don't believe you can make your binding redirects separate from the main application config.

Your only other option would be to handle the [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event to handle binding failures. But this is potentially expensive as the runtime will exhaust [all of its options for probing the assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx) before raising this event.